# How to share desktop when no network is shown?

Tags: networking, 18.04, remote-desktop

I have Ubuntu 18.04 connected to a wired network:

[image: wired network]

But when I try to share my desktop I don't have any network available:

[image: any network available]

How am I supposed to share my desktop if I cannot select any network?

Comment: What do you mean “share your desktop”? Do you want to control your Ubuntu installation or access its files remotely from other systems? Do you want to share the network connection with other connected systems?

Comment: I want to share the screen and the access to files.

Comment: We’re sorry, Ask Ubuntu is not a forum but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions, one for each of the two topics, and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Comment: It is just a question. Ubuntu has a way to share the screen but no network is available to share it (when I am connected to a network...)

Comment: File sharing and desktop sharing are two separate topics.

Comment: Yes, that's why I clarified it is just a question about desktop sharing.

Comment: Sorry about the misunderstanding. Could you please [edit] your post when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: Did you managed to activate desktop sharing?

Comment: Yes, if I remember correctly, the problem was with /etc/network/interfaces. I had there the configuration of my network and in "settings" wasn't it shown until I rebooted Network Manager.